# UITableView scrolls when data source is added with more elements and variable cell height

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll

I have a tableview data source initially with 20 elements. Later the datasource is updated with more elements. To update the tableview i call a tableview reload. When it is called the scroll position changes suddenly. Is there a way i can stop it from scrolling and make it remain where i was looking at?

So i found out why exactly the scrolling happens. I have implemented heightForRowAtIndex and when i commented it out the table view does not scroll automatically. But i still havent found a solution to this

Comment: it would be better if you post your code as well so that one could check where you are actually getting wrong

Answer (score 0):

I think you a wrong with your description .. i tried to do as you said, i create a table view with 20 elements , added a button that adding 20 element and called "reloadData". The result was that the table did't move or scroll. the new data was added to the end of the table. i saw it after i scroll to the end of the table.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


self.arr = [NSMutableArray new];

for (self.i=0;  self.i<10; self.i++) {
    [self.arr addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",self.i]];
}

[self.tableView setDelegate:self];
[self.tableView setDataSource:self];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return self.arr.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

[cell.textLabel setText:self.arr[indexPath.row]];

return cell;
}
- (IBAction)addMoreDataToArr:(id)sender {
int oldI = self.i;
for (self.i = self.i;  self.i<oldI+10; self.i++) {
    [self.arr addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",self.i]];
}

[self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

FYI: this is very poor code :) it just for the POC!